# Storing heterogeanous class type in a variable

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm a beginner with c++ :), I simplified my problem to this:

I have a class Person

```
class Person{
    string name;}
```

And another class Student that inherits Person

```
class Student : public Person{
    string schoolName;}
```

And then I have a class Library that must have a different comportement depending on the input

```
class Library{
   void checkBeforeEntry(Person* p){
       cout << "You must be a student to enter" << endl;}
   void checkBeforeEntry(Student* s){
       cout << "You can enter" << endl;}}
```

At some point in my programm I'm storing a person like that: `Person* guy;`
because at that point I don't know yet if he is a simple person or a student.

But due to that I'm "loosing" the information about the real type of the object and I have tried this:

```
    Person *p = new Person();
    Student *s = new Student();
    Person *g = new Student();

    lib.checkBeforeEntry(p);
    lib.checkBeforeEntry(s);
    lib.checkBeforeEntry(g);
```

The Output was:

```
You must be a student to enter
You can enter
You must be a student to enter
```

But I want the last statement to be "you can enter".
I used a bit of polymorphism before to adapt the comportement of the derived class but here I'm trying to change the comportement of a third party class (library) so the situation is not the same as I am used to. Do you know how to solve this or if I should use another design ?

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to check if your `Person` pointer is really pointing at a `Student`. Not sure if that's a good idea or not without seeing more of your code, but it would work. The only requirement is that there must be at least one virtual function in `Person`. You can make a virtual destructor if there is no other function you want to make virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to cast downwards which will only succeed (i.e return a non `nullptr` value) if the runtime type is correct.

Applied to your situation:

```
void checkBeforeEntry(Person* p){
    if (dynamic_cast<Student*>(p)) {
       std::cout << "You can enter" << std::endl;
    } else {
       std::cout << "Only students can enter" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This has the downside however, that it requires Runtime Type Information (RTTI) to be enabled and might be quite costly (as usual implementations look up and check RTTI informations stored right next to the vftable). Also it requires you to specify specific types (imagine how adding `Professor`, `Librarian`, etc. classes would bloat the above code)

An arguably better approach can be to declare a `virtual bool isStudent()` or `virtual bool canEnterLibrary()` on `Person`

Comment: If a solution requires `dynamic_cast` it usually means that it isn't the right solution. This solution is not extensible and will break down as you add new kinds of `Person`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! That's great because I can access the variable of the derived class by doing the dynamic cast. I think I will go for that one

Comment: @Delmak Again, please do not use `dynamic_cast` to perform dispatching. This is bypassing polymorphism. The language has a feature specifically to accomplish.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I wholeheartly agree with you

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok I just saw what you suggest that's clever because I don't have to use dynamic_cast and I can still access to the attributes thanks :)

Comment: @Delmak My answer also has problems and I removed it. I recommend you look at Hack06's answer.

Comment: I needed to make a token edit to remove the downvote. It seems like `dynamic_cast` is needed here and the least harmful quick fix. There is likely a design problem though if this solution is actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you are using here is called a static-polymorphism. Which means that the type checking is taking place at compile-time and not run-time. I.e. the type of the pointers is deciding the type of the objects and hence the version of the overloaded function `checkBeforeEntry()` to be called.

To achieve what you want, and in a simplest way with the minimal impact on the existing code you have, I think the following can be the best.

```
class Person {
public:
    string name;
    virtual bool passLibrary() const {return false;}
    virtual ~Person();
};

class Student: public Person {
public:
    string schoolName;
    bool passLibrary() const override {return true;}
    virtual ~Student();
};

class Library {
public:
    void checkBeforeEntry(const Person *p) const {
        if (p->passLibrary()) {
            cout << "You can enter" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "You must be a student to enter" << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

So here the function `passLibrary()` is a virtual function, which means it'll use the dynamic-polymorphism, i.e. check the current object type at run-time, and each of your classes Person and Student will provide their own implementation, which will be used by the class Library to distinguish easily between Person and Student objects.

I hope this was clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your explainations about type checking (at run time or compile).

Comment: You are most welcome. Consider accepting an answer among the responses as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person {
    string name;
  public:
    virtual ~Person() = default;
    virtual bool isStudent() const { return false; }
};

class Student : public Person {
    string schoolName;
  public:
    bool isStudent() const override { return true; }
};

class Library {
    void checkBeforeEntry(Person* p) {
       if (!p->isStudent())
           cout << "You must be a student to enter" << endl;
       else
           cout << "You can enter" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: This type of solution is not extendable. As you add more kinds of `Person` you potentially need to update every derived type to add a new `isType()` member function.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I like it, very simple, however I can't access the variable of the derived class like this : cout << "You are a student of" << p->schoolName << " , you can enter"; right ?

Comment: @Delmak The type system doesn't knows that `p` points to a `Student` so it won't let you use `schoolName` there. You need to manually cast to `Student` to tell the type system to treat it as such. But this is not a good solution, it's a patch for a weak fix to your problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux do you defend your own solution by voting down other solutions?

Comment: @S.M. I downvoted this answer before answering because it is bad advice. I answered because 3 other people got it wrong. We don't need bad answers forming more bad developers. We have enough of those already. This solution works here this time, because of how limited to scope of the code is but it is a bad habit. Inevitably, this habit will be applied where it isn't appropriate and will cause harm then.

Comment: Ok thank, So if I want to do something clean I shouldn't have mixed students and persons in the first place ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Your solution is also not well, requires to add `checkBeforeEntry` for each new child type.

Comment: So you agree your posted solution is very bad, it requires updating the parent class on each additional child class.

Comment: Ok, I would like to add DiedPerson inheriting Person. Can it enter the library?

Comment: @S.M. You're right. Edit : that my solution has the same flaw. Edit 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581077/7359094 got it right.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm buffled that you belief the solution you posted is somehow the cannonical way for this issue. Using the implicit type of `this` in a virtual method to then use static dispatching with regular overload resolution seems really convoluted and unclean for me. While I see the appeal of having two overloads, it also means that outsiders could circumvent the design and call a particular overload as they desire. While its definitely an interessting design, I just wanted to let you know, that I don't belief it to be a perfect or ideal solution

Comment: Please don't remove your answer, it is not an ideal but is a legal alternative. I just don't like you have downvoated my answer.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I didn't pay attention to how `Library` was implemented. I removed it in favor of Hack06's.

Comment: @S.M. I removed it because it has the same bad advice. I considered fixing it but it would just be the same as the answer I linked earlier. There is no benefit to having the same answer twice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Its inherent. As soon as you abstract something you loose information, because thats exactly what abstraction is. If you want to introduce specificness back to the problem, you have to perform some kind of check. Whether that is `dynamic_cast`, a member variable (notice that passing type information to parent ctor is also a valid option), vftable lookups (i.e dynamic dispatchs) or your double-dispatch design doesn't matter because they all do the same thing. They use some dynamic property to identify the underlying type.

Comment: In the end it boils down to a matter of taste and the specific context and design. While i'm not a fan of dynamic_cast either i dont like treating it as a secret. Its a valid tool after all.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Templates instantly remove the "dynamicness" of the problem. E.g you couldn't get the desired behaviour anymore when dealing with a `std::vector<Person*>`.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann You're right, this is double dispatching. I didn't consider it because there is only one obvious inheritance tree here. This is a design problem them. It depends on what `checkBeforeEntry` wants to do, depending on the `Person` type. Edit : My idea was to template `checkBeforeEntry` so you would always have the concrete type. But that is a garbage idea because you would have to treat it as a `Person` anyway. I just didn't see the double dispatch until now.